# Pydispatcher or AMQP/RabbitMQ for local event driven processing written in python?

Tags: python, events, rabbitmq, amqp

I am developing a t`rading/position management system` in `Python`. It is therefore going to interact with external software, database events, and also on timed events as well.

Is it efficient enough to use a `AMQP` like `RabbitMQ` to handle everything? Or should I use a `PyDispatcher` for local events and AMQP for external events?

Are both these solutions going to be slower than just say, a normal function call from one python script to another imported python script?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The right answer to your question depends on your architecture. If you're adopting a microservices-style architecture, it might make sense to use AMQP for all your event communication. If you're adopting more of a monolithic architecture, you may want to use PyDispatcher + AMQP.

Note that AMQP and RabbitMQ shouldn't be used interchangeably. AMQP is a protocol. RabbitMQ implements a specific version of AMQP (0.9 and 0.9.1). ActiveMQ (broker), Apache Qpid (broker), Apache Qpid Proton (client), and Microsoft Azure (cloud service) support AMQP 1.0.